# How to use hex color value in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

When I set custom color to some form in Expressions window, the formula looks like 
`#117be0`
or 
`="#117be0"`

So, the question is, how to get string color hex value from dataset that contains the same value?
Something like this
`=First(Fields!my_color.Value, "color_dataset")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you kind of answered your own question. Yes, FIRST() will return the first value in the colors dataset. To make this more meaningful, you are going to want to used the LOOKUP function.

> LOOKUP(Fields!Local_Dataset_Value.Value, Fields!Color_Dataset_Value.Value, Fields!my_color.Value, "color_dataset")

Lookup will check the value of the Local_Dataset_Value field in your current table dataset, and find a match for that value in the "color_dataset" dataset's Color_Dataset_Value field. When it finds a match, then your color will return.

To explain further, given datasets:

> Dataset1
>
> Name | Age | Etc
>
> ........................
>
> Joe  |  30 | Whatever

and

> color_dataset
>
> Color_Name | my_color
>
> .....................
>
> Joe  | Blue

then:

> LOOKUP(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Color_Name.Value, Fields!my_color.Value, "color_dataset")

Would return:

> "Blue"